# How to make a batch file to search all drives?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

How can I get this batch file to read all physical and mapped drives? It works fine with C: but will not read any other drive.

```
@echo off
set filePath=
for /R c:\ /d %%a in (*) do if exist "%%a\FileName" set filePath=%%a& goto continue
:continue
if defined filePath echo %COMPUTERNAME% %username% yes >> \\server\%computername%.txt
```

Comment: Does it have to be a `.bat` batch file, or can it be a `.ps` PowerShell file? (You list Windows 7 as the OS, and Powershell comes standard on Windows 7. It's like `cmd.exe` on steroids)

Comment: 'Xcept it's legal!

Answer (score 2):

There's no variable that simply carries all mapped letters.

if you're running as admin,

> fsutil fsinfo drives

returns all such drives- an example bit of code:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%a IN (`MOUNTVOL ^| FIND ":\"`) DO (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3" %%b IN (`FSUTIL FSINFO DRIVETYPE %%a`) DO (IF /I "%%b" EQU "Removable" ECHO %%a ))
```

(play with the outputs)

... if not workable, you're gonna have to blast through them all, ie:

> for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO @if exist %%i: @echo %%i:

(probably should omit the expected optical drive/memory-card drive letters).

VBS-scripting, or Powershell is ideal for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

`if exist %%i` : not always work. So you can also check your drives with this way :

```
(dir %%i:>NUL) && (
  echo Drive [%%i]: exist
) || (
  echo Drive [%%i]: NOT exist
)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Maybe my post should be moved as a comment of the answer of @solemnity